# Android - Error converting bytecode to dex

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

The app was working fine until I added a couple of libraries in the gradle file,
I added the Google analytics and Admob library (which worked fine but the others who had the same problem said that Google Analytics library is the source of this error) and recently I added a third party library for styling a custom material design Scrollbar

**Update** I got the third party library for the scrollbar [FROM HERE](https://github.com/timusus/RecyclerView-FastScroll)

**Here's my dependencies :**

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
  compile 'com.simplecityapps:recyclerview-fastscroll:1.0.11' //The scrollbar library
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Event Log:**

```
Information:Gradle tasks[:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Comment: please share the link of custom material design Scrollbar library

Comment: Please check the updated part of he question

Comment: i just added it in my project and everything works fine and compiles.Try inserting one by one and then you will see which library you get error from.

Comment: I also get this error just the before the gradle build finishes : `PSI and index do not match: PSI and index do not match`