# Android - Gradle build error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After I got two errors related to converting bytecode to dex ([read more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827973/android-error-converting-bytecode-to-dex)) I updated the firebase library from `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'` to `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'` after doing that I noticed that the problem is almost solved but after building this is what I got:

**EVENT LOG**

```
00:49:13 RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
00:51:23 RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
00:52:57 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 6m 38s 458ms
00:52:58 EmptyThrowable: Merged rootsChanged not allowed inside rootsChanged, rootsChanged level == 1
```

**GRADLE BUILD MESSAGE**

```
Error:Execution failed for    task ':app:transformClassesWithDependencyCheckerForDebug'.
> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.DescriptiveChange cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.InputFileDetails
he may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires   network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may becorrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```